# Splitting nested list of floats to columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested, multiple-columns

I just started to learn Python and I am doing an assignment.

I have a nested list that consist of rows with float numbers:

```
list_of_rows = [[0.888181, 0.684158], [0.389394, 0.733662], [0.73079, 0.673245], [0.813126, 0.805672], [0.789109, 0.559043]]
```

I have to write a function called transpose_data that turns the list of lists around so that it becomes a list of columns, rather than a list of rows.

I was thinking about using a for loop and the split function to split by the commas, but split only works on strings.

Can anyone help me or give me a hint?

Comment: Well the comma is *not* part of the list. What you see is a *textual representation* of the string.

Comment: That being said, this Q shows (close to) no effort. That is not how it works. At least explain how you would transpose the list (in English) for instance.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem and it's a duplicate.